# Android Vertical View Pager like NewsInShort Application

Tags: android

How to create a vertical view pager in android like in the NewsInShort App.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nis.app

This app contains news feed and when we slide up the current news the next news appear with the animation like if i swipe up the current news a little bit then the next news shows like that way.
Same for the swipe down.

I have found a library on Github. 
https://github.com/rharter/ViewPager-Android

But this library doesn't provide anything like NewsInShort App.

If anyone ever created the view or library like that, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research, i have found the solution.
To the ViewPager we can set the pageTransformer property and can assign the custom Transformation.
The transformation that i want is the DepthPageTransformer. Below is the link where this transformation is documented.
https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/animation/screen-slide.html#depth-page

```
public class DepthPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    private static float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;

    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.setAlpha(0);

        } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
            // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
            view.setAlpha(1);
            view.setTranslationX(0);
            view.setScaleX(1);
            view.setScaleY(1);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
            // Fade the page out.
            view.setAlpha(1 - position);

            // Counteract the default slide transition
            view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);

            // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
            float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                    + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Although it's too late answer, but it could be help someone else who want to create animation (viewpager transformer) like inshorts app.

```
public class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager {

public VerticalViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public VerticalViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());
    setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}


/**
 * Swaps the X and Y coordinates of your touch event.
 */
private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {
    float width = getWidth();
    float height = getHeight();

    float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
    float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;

    ev.setLocation(newX, newY);

    return ev;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
    swapXY(ev); // return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views
    return intercepted;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
}

public class DepthPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;

    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.setAlpha(0);

        } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
            // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
            view.setAlpha(1);
            view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

            //set Y position to swipe in from top
            float yPosition = position * view.getHeight();
            view.setTranslationY(yPosition);
            view.setScaleX(1);
            view.setScaleY(1);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
            // Fade the page out.
            view.setAlpha(1 - position);

            // Counteract the default slide transition
            view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);

            // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
            float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                    + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }
}
```

}

> and you need to use VerticalViewPager in xml